# How can I change the width of the scrollbar on a textarea?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I have a dynamic text area that receives text via XML, and when the text is big enough, the scroll bar shows up. How can I change the width of the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the skins for all flash components in your library in a sub folder called "**Component Assets**".  In the case of scroll bars, they are in a folder called "**ScrollBarSkins**".

[image]

Take note that there are many pieces that make up the various states of the scroll bar.

You can edit those skins to be the size/color look that you desire.